# Removing "\n" from a line got from fgets()

Tags: c

What I want to do is the following:

- read **1st** line from **file.txt**
- **remove** the **\n** from it.
- print it

For that purpose, my code is:

```
main(){
    char line_one[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    fgets(line_one, sizeof line_one, fp);

    printf("%s", line_one);

    char line_one_NEW[100];
    strncpy(line_one_NEW, line_one, strlen(line_one)-1);

    printf("%s", line_one_NEW);

    return 0;
}
```

The result that I am getting is:

```
test
test�{r
```

Why is there *strange* stuff after the **line_one_NEW** ?

Comment: `strncpy()`, despite its name, was not designed to work with *strings*. It does not deal with `'\0'` in the usual way: it may leave the terminator out of the final array or it may fill the array with several of them.

Comment: `fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");` -> Could do with checking if `fp` is not null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Answer (score 4):

Use `strrchr` for a reverse search.

```
char* pos = strrchr(line_one, '\n');
if (pos) *pos = 0;
```

Your method that copies the string over is incorrect, because you miss to add a null character to terminate the string.

Comment: I like to see old-hands answers. Beat me sir! +1

Comment: `strchr()` should also work. `fgets()` will never write two (or more) `'\n'` to the array.

Comment: What if input has `\n` per se? @pmg

Comment: @snr: the following characters are buffered, ready to be read on the (probable) next time through the loop.

Comment: @snr `fgets()` stops at the first `\n`, that's the whole point of the function.

Comment: The workings of `strchr()` and `strrchr()` on a string coming from `fgets()` should be very similar. Nevertheless, `strchr()` is, for me, easier to visualize.

Comment: This is interesting, but the *actual* question is: *"Why is there strange stuff after the line_one_NEW ?"*

Comment: @NisseEngström-- the title of the question is, "removing `\n` from a line that comes from `fgets()`."

Comment: Note that strrchr doesn't do a reverse search, it still searches forwards, but returns the location of the last match found.  As we are searching for the end of the string though, there isn't a (significant) difference in performance (`strrchr` will go on to read the `null`)

Comment: @DavidBowling: That's not a question, it's a statement. It seems to describe the purpose of the code. The question is asked in the *body* of the post, as you'd expect.

Comment: @NisseEngström-- it is the _title_ of the question. I would say that it is the main thrust of the question. I see the question about behavior as a secondary question. IAC, I think you are being overly pedantic about this.

Comment: @DavidBowling: So the OP wrote a bad title. That doesn't excuse anyone from not reading the rest of the post. The *important* issue here is the missing string terminator. It's a subtle and hard-to-find bug and *that* needs addressing. The other stuff is largely irrelevant. - This is C programming we're talking about; you're not being pedantic enough.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest solution i think is strcspn() to remove \n:

```
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: `strcspn` is already too complicated, since the second argument is a string, too. And then your method has undesired results if there isn't any newline present.

Comment: @JensGustedt no, this method is safe. `strcspn()` will return the index of the `0` terminator if no "unaccepted" character is found.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes,this worked for me as a charm always

Comment: How is this supposed to be applied to the code in the question? It doesn't have a `buffer` identifier. And you haven't answered *the actual* question: *"Why is there strange stuff after the line_one_NEW ?"*

Answer (score 2):

For starters to remove the new line character from a string you can use the following trick

```
line_one[ strcspn( line_one, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

As for this code snippet

```
strncpy(line_one_NEW, line_one, strlen(line_one)-1);
printf("%s", line_one_NEW);
```

then at first it is logically wrong because in general the new line character can be absent in the string `line_one`. In this case the expression for the number of copied characters

```
strlen(line_one)-1
```

will be wrong.

But in any case if you use the standard function `strncpy` you should explicitly to append a terminating zero. For example

```
strncpy(line_one_NEW, line_one, strlen(line_one)-1);
line_one_NEW[strlen(line_one)-1] = '\0';
```

Or if you want to copy the first line into the second line without the new line character but keeping the new line character in the first line then you can write

```
size_t n = strcspn( line_one, "\n" );
strncpy( line_one_NEW, line_one, n );
line_one_NEW[n] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

`char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );`

No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow).

Therefore, it should be:

```
char line_one_NEW[100] = {0};
strncpy(line_one_NEW, line_one, strlen(line_one)-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove  the "\n" from the line you need to write this code line after the fgets(I will write the line of the fgets too):

```
fgets(str,MAX_CHARACTERS,fp); 
//MAX_CHARACTERS is the maximum of characters that you want to get from the fgets
str[strcspn(str,"\n")]=0;
```

Hope that my comment was helpful for you ;)

Answer (score -5):

```
strncpy(arg1 , arg2 ,  integer);
```

a function in the `string.h` library means Copy first n chars of `arg2`  into `arg1`

```
strlen(str) :
```

a function in the `string.h` library  , is used to count the number of the characters in the string str and return integer int , Because we don't want to write '/n' , so it avoids last character which is '/n'by writing

```
strlen(line_one)-1
```

Comment: You're just repeating what OP was already doing and you're also failing at writing a `'\0'` at the end of the new string.